# How to turn on always the microphone in bot framework direct line

Tags: c#, botframework, speech-to-text, direct-line-botframework

I'm creating a bot which accept text and voice input and also can answer in both mode. 
The bot works really good but i have to click always the button of microphone to speak with the bot. Do you know it is possible to make microphone always on and to recognize the voice without clicking the button of microphone ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework- 
webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
   <body>
   <div id="bot" />
   <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework- 
    webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework- 
 webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js"></script>
        <script> var speechOptions = {
          speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer(
        { subscriptionKey: 'xxxxxx' }),

            speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer(
        {
            subscriptionKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
            voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, 
    JessaRUS)'
        })
  }

    var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
     secret: "zzzzzzzzzz",
    webSocket: true,
   });


BotChat.App({
        speechOptions: speechOptions,
        botConnection: botConnection,
        user: {
            id: 'userid',
            name: 'User',
        },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect',
        locale: 'en-US'

    },

function postHelp() {
    botConnection
        .postActivity({
            from: { id: 'userid', name: 'User' },
            name: 'postHelp',
            type: 'message',
            text: 'help'
        })
        .subscribe(function(id) {
            console.log('"postHelp" sent');
        });
};

function welcome() {
    botConnection
        .postActivity({
            from: { id: 'userid', name: 'User' },
            name: 'welcome',
            type: 'event',
            value: 'help'
        })
        .subscribe(function (id) {
            console.log('"welcome" sent');
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: There isn't enough here to recreate the situation you're asking about. If you could please post the minimum reproducible code, in particular a portion of your RootDialog.cs that shows your message Activity.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes There's no need to add a RootDialog here, the problem is around the Webchat component

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just turn on such a behavior. To have something like this, you have to implement the whole thing yourself, editing the code of the [web chat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). The web chat control is using the [Direct Line API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) under the hood through the [DirectLineJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) library.

Comment: i have implement DirectLine and was working ...the point is to let the microphone on ...not to click the button of microphone everytime the user have to say something.

Comment: In this moment is : click the microphone button , say a phrase ...await for an answer , then do the same thing again

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying. There's no out of the box support for this in the web chat control. You have to fork the source code of it and implement the functionality yourself.